# I want to Add product quantity increment like 2pkt,4pkt and 8pkt and i also want to discount

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to Add product quantity increment like 2pkt,4pkt and 8pkt and i also want to discount like 2pkt with 7% , 4pkt with 10% and 8pkt with 15% give discount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tier pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=701WaPcRk_Q).
It allows you to set different prices for different quantities (even for different customer groups if needed).
The only downside is you will have to calculate the prices by hand. Tire pricing does not support percentage prices.

Comment: thanks for answer   but i want to quantity only 2,4 and 8 but i add quantity 6 its count price to 4pkt tier price, i also use dropdown box but its show 1 to 9999 value what i do